# Serverless lamdas uses cached handler code, yet watcher detected changes and recompiles. How to fix?

Tags: node.js, caching, lambda, serverless

Our setup uses basic serverless library with:

- serverless-offline plugin
- serverless-webpack or serverless-typescript plugin
- Node

What is happening:
File system watcher is running. And is properly triggered everytime you make a change in your source. It should support hot module replacement. Yet the output of Lambda handler doesn't change.

What should happen:
Lamda handler code should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve that upgrade you serverless-offline library.

Not-affected versions are bellow `6.0.0` (with additional issues) and above `6.8.0` (working properly)

This bug was reported to owners or serverless-offline repository and was resolved with caveats.

--
There are multiple bug reports in github and no clear answer.